# What could be wrong with my CD drive and how do you fix it?

Tags: compact-disc, optical-drive

My CD drive hasn't worked in about 8 months. I was burning CDs in a hurry and pulled it out because it was taking too long (probably an average amount of time). Im running a laptop (Toshiba Satellite A505-6965) that uses a slot drive.

Now my computer doesn't accept CDs. It used to pull them in but it doesn't anymore. Ive heard it make odd noises a few times but thats it. The slot is these spongey things and Ive managed to peek into the drive with a flashlight and theres nothing in the way, really.

Could someone explain the mechanics of what happened and if it would be possible to fix it? If itd be possible to fix it through Linux that would be great since I keep getting the BSOD (0x0000007B) and am going to try reinstalling Windows 7. But I can't really do that since I don't have a USB drive larger than 2 GB (Windows is about 4 GB) so Im relying on Linux ATM.

Comment: Try to get CD installed onto another system and see if its working on the other(try with other combination like different OS, all the drivers installed). See if its working, then you come to the conclusion that there is something wrong with your original host perhaps with drivers or files. If not, time to visit the CD repairer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you used force to pull out the CD you may have damaged the mechanism that physically loads and ejects the CD.

To repair this you will have to open the computer, remove CD-drive, disassemble it and inspect the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If unable to test in another system. it might be easiest to just replace the drive.  Prices are pretty low for CD or DVD drives.

Answer (score 1):

*I was burning CDs in a hurry and pulled it out because it was taking too long (probably an average amount of time).* Watched someone do that on a Mac Mini with similar results.

Reminds me of the old Army Field Engineer rule, "If it's not working, force it. If it breaks, it needed replacing anyway."

The internals of these drives are delicate and small tolerance. If it's been forced enough to break or bend something, it's not likely the laser will properly focus anymore aside from the obvious that the loader mechanism has been rendered inoperable. It's not likely you're going to be able to fix it, so your only recourse is to replace it.

As has been recommended elsewhere, try it in another machine and then sling it into the nearest recycle bin and get a new one when its proved to be inoperable.